# Checkmark not showing in tablecell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark

I have a tableview where on tap of cell it displays checkmark. But before displaying cells, if cell met certain condition it should be displayed with checkmark accessory

In my cellforRow code

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myConstants.detailCell, for: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    if let checkIndex = selectedIndex, checkIndex == indexPath.row {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark //THis did not work so added next line
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false) // This also did not work
        cell.configureCell(with: infoDataSource, at: indexPath.row, isChecked: true) //Updated my configure cell method to show accessory type like below..but none of them works
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
        cell.configureCell(with: infoDataSource, at: indexPath.row)
    }
```

None of my cells are displaying checkmark on when tableview is first shown. It is getting displayed when I tap on cell but checkmark should also appear if certain condition is met.. below is my configure cell method of DetailTableViewCell

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configureCell(with data: NotesListModel?, at index: Int, isChecked: Bool = false) {
    guard let cellData = data?.noteName(at: index) else {
        return
    }
    self.textLabel?.text = cellData
    self.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.accessoryType = isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

Here also I'm trying to set self.accessoryType but also it doesnt show when tableview is displayed. What am I missing here? Please advice

Comment: You are trying to set the accessoryType in two places - cellForRowAt and configureCell. Pick one.

Comment: I started with one..since that's not working i tried to add multiple

Comment: Use the debugger and see what actually happens and confirm the values of the various variables involved.

Comment: it executes cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark  but still no checkmark is visible

Comment: What is the value of `selectedIndex` when your tableView first loads and how/when are you setting it? Note that only one cell in the table can have `selectedIndex == indexPath.row`.

Comment: yes correct, there will always be one record selected. And that will be determined by selectedIndex. Here selectedIndex value is 1 whereas my datasource contains 10records. So record at index 1 should always be selected

Comment: @rmaddy : After debugging i noticed that setSelected calls after my configure cell method. So it is resetting the checkmark. Issue is fixed now. Thanks

Comment: @ash4 Your comment save my time, thanks man!